# Configuring OpenDDS

Tags: perl, gcc, opendds

I am trying to configure the environment for OpenDDS, but I could not run the configure script. Would really appreciate much, if there are any insight from you guys. =D

So basically, after I download the OpenDDS-3.12.zip from [here](http://download.objectcomputing.com/OpenDDS/). I have extracted to a folder and tried to run the configure file with this command in VS command prompt (VS2017)

```
configure --compiler=gcc
```

Next, the "ACE+TAO-2.2a_with_latest_patches_NO_makefiles" is downloaded and I extract the zip file to the root folder.

Then it shows this message.

```
ACE_ROOT/ace/config.h exists, skipping configuration of ACE+TAO 
Use of uninitialized value $mpctype in string eq at configure line 1103.                                                
Use of uninitialized value $mpctype in concatenation (.) or string at configure line 1257.                              
Use of uninitialized value $mpctype in string eq at configure line 1266.                                                
Running MPC to generate project files.                                                                                  
MPC_ROOT was set to C:\src\OpenDDS-DDS-3.12.2\ACE_wrappers\MPC.                                                         
Using .../OpenDDS-DDS- 
3.12.2/ACE_wrappers/bin/MakeProjectCreator/config/MPC.cfg                                         
ERROR: Invalid type: C:\src\OpenDDS-DDS-3.12.2\DDS_TAOv2_all.mwc                                                        
mwc.pl v4.1.28                                                                                                          

...
/*lots of explanation of each file here*
*then followed by*/
...

ERROR: Error from MPC, stopped at configure line 1270.
```

I have both Visual Studio 2017 and Perl 5.22 installed as well, I am not sure whether if this is a compiler issue or any other issue. The following is the configure script that printed the error above.

```
@@ line 1268 -- 1270 @@
  if (!$opts{'dry-run'}) {
if (system("perl \"$ENV{'ACE_ROOT'}/bin/mwc.pl\" $mwcargs") != 0) {
  die "ERROR: Error from MPC, stopped";
}
}
```

Comment: Figure out where `$mpctype` is defined, maybe you are missing an environmental variable or command switch.

Comment: Also, generally the first warning / error is the most useful for looking at the code, not the last, so here I would start looking before line 1103 instead of line 1266.

Comment: Don't use `--compiler=gcc`, you are not using gcc but Visual Studio

Comment: Maybe I should start with the base of the problem. When I tried to use only `--compiler` , it show me this instead, 

`ERROR: Can't find a compiler, set PATH or run this script with the --compiler option. For Microsoft Visual C++, run this script from the Visual Studio Command Prompt. 
Stopped at configure line 378.`
I have check my PATH in my system, that perl is in it, or is there anything I missed out?

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen, so which command should I use? It seems to can't find a compiler.

Comment: You should the command from a Visual Studio command prompt, are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

`$mpctype` is defined here:

```
my $mpctype = ($slash eq '/' ||
              ($cross_compile && $buildEnv->{'build'} eq 'target'))
            ? 'gnuace' : $opts{'compiler_version'};
```

It seems to be looking at `$opts{'compiler_version'}`, which is apparently empty. `%opts` is defined here:

```
my %opts = %{parseArgs()};
```

so it looks like you should define the `compiler_version` in the command line or define the target platform. It's probably better if you [check out the INSTALL options thoroughly](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/DDS-3.12.2/INSTALL)

Comment: I have checked the INSTALL options, but still no where to any solution. The TAO and ACE environment is correct. how do you define `compiler_version`?

Comment: @LeonTeng You can try --compiler_version=dummy and see what it does, but maybe you can try "gcc" and other you might have installed in your system.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight, problem is solved. It is the missing compiler in Visual Studio that caused the problem. Apparently Visual Studio did not install C++ by default, so what to do it is just rerun the setup, select modify and check C++, and then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

VS2017 doesn't install c++ compiler by default.

> - Modify VS 2017 and select c++ compiler and install if VS 2017 already install.
> - configure (without --compiler=gcc flag)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question. Being a newbie, I started with the getting started with java and windows on https://opendds.org/quickstart/GettingStartedWindows.html .
Step 5, "configure (To enable Java support, use configure --java)" didn't work in a visual studio command window despite
having set JAVA_HOME. I had sent ACE_ROOT, DDS_ROOT, TAO_ROOT and MPC_ROOT though the tutorial didn't specify based on trying to debug this problem.
When using the "--compiler" option I get errors similar to the ones in this thread. Was there any resolution just to get the"
"off-the-shelf" tutorial working. Using Windows 10.

D:\data\OpenDDS-3.13.3>configure --java --compiler="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin"
    ACE_ROOT/ace/config.h exists, skipping configuration of ACE+TAO
    Use of uninitialized value $mpctype in string eq at configure line 1482.
    Use of uninitialized value $mpctype in concatenation (.) or string at configure line 
    1646.
    Use of uninitialized value $mpctype in string eq at configure line 1655.
    Running MPC to generate project files.
    MPC_ROOT was set to D:\data\OpenDDS-3.13.3\ACE_WRAPPERS\MPC.
    Using .../OpenDDS-3.13.3/ACE_WRAPPERS/bin/MakeProjectCreator/config/MPC.cfg
    ERROR: Invalid type: D:\data\OpenDDS-3.13.3\DDS_TAOv2_all.mwc
    mwc.pl v4.1.44
    ...
    ERROR: Error from MPC, stopped at configure line 1659.

Comment: Hi user8039286, welcome. Please consider giving a better format, it's very hard to read as it is.